# Mx player says unsupported android version for 4.3

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, mx-player

I have installed 4.3 yesterday on my Nexus 4, and since that time MX player would not load, saying:

> unsupported android version

Is there a workaround, or do I have to wait until the developers change the API level check? As far as I know there is nothing in 4.3 that makes a code change neccessary.

I have tried RealPlayer as well, it says the same. There might have been some serious changes after all.
Then again, VLC player is working.

I am more and more confused.

Comment: While you wait as geffchang said, raise this to the developer's attention.

Comment: The last two minor updates to MX Player both released over the last 3 days have both listed compatibility fixes for Android 4.3, and for Restricted Profiles with Android 4.3. It's now working fine on my 4.3 phone. So it's worth trying again now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait until they release a version that's compatible with Android 4.3.

For the mean time, you can try other players like [BSPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bsplayer.bspandroid.full) or [VPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.abitno.vplayer.t). They're working with 4.3.

**Update #1:** As of 2013-08-07, based on GAThrawn's comments, MX Player now works with Android 4.3

Comment: The last two minor updates to MX Player both released over the last 3 days have both listed compatibility fixes for Android 4.3, and for Restricted Profiles with Android 4.3. It's now working fine on my 4.3 phone.

Comment: @GAThrawn Thanks! Added your feedback as UPDATE #1

Answer (score 2):

As [geffchang](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/5342/geffchang) said, [VPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.abitno.vplayer.t) is a good alternative.

If you are still looking for MX Player, here is the [test build](https://sites.google.com/site/mxvpen/translation/test-build), which works perfectly with 4.3 version.

Comment: It does not work on my device, with the hardware decoder it gives a black screen, but the subtitles are there. Without it a film is loaded, some circle rotates for 1 second, than the next file is loaded in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

[VLC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon) seems to be working fine on my 4.3 update on my Nexus.